# Fetching journal URLs with CORE API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, database

I am trying to fetch some journal data which includes but not limited to the title and URL of the journals using CORE API in React. I want to provide links that take the user to the location specified in the URL field.
This is what the API returns.

```
{
  "identifiers": [
    "oai:doaj.org/journal:fc6f85dc44ed458b983814eb3628da53",
    "issn:1179-1497",
    "url:http://doaj.org/toc/fc6f85dc44ed458b983814eb3628da53"
  ],
  "language": "English",
  "publisher": "Dove Medical Press",
  "subjects": [
    "neuropsychiatry",
    "behavioral complications",
    "HIV research",
    "AIDS research",
    "pathology",
    "LCC:Neurosciences. Biological psychiatry. Neuropsychiatry",
    "LCC:RC321-571",
    "LCC:Internal medicine",
    "LCC:RC31-1245",
    "LCC:Medicine",
    "LCC:R"
  ],
  "dataProviderId": "645",
  "title": "Neurobehavioral HIV Medicine"
}
```

So far I made just a basic prototype component that displays the list of some computer science journals with their titles but I am having a difficult time extracting the URLs and using them as hrefs. As you can see above the API returns an 'identifiers' field which contains the URLs but as a string like this: "url:[https://doaj.org/toc/1549-3636"](https://doaj.org/toc/1549-3636%22). How can I extract the link from there and make it work? Also, please if you know any other API that will make my work easier please let me know.

```
const JournalList = () => {
  const [journals, setJournals] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchJournals();
  }, []);

  const fetchJournals = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://core.ac.uk:443/api-v2/journals/search/computer%20science?pageSize=10&apiKey=API_KEY"
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      const transformedJournals = data.data.map((journal) => ({
        title: journal.title,
        url: journal.identifiers[2] || "",
      }));
      console.log(transformedJournals);
      setJournals(transformedJournals);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>List of Journals</h2>
      {journals.length === 0 ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {journals.map((journal) => (
            <li key={journal.title}>
              <h3>{journal.title}</h3>
              {journal.url ? (
                // <a href={journal.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                //   {journal.url}
                // </a>
                <p>{journal.url}</p>
              ) : (
                <p>No URL available</p>
              )}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default JournalList;
```

Comment: If that’s your real api key: revoke them now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Notes**

You were close to what is needed, you just needed to fix the url by slicing off the first 4 characters. But I would clean up your fetchJournals function a bit so that it is easier to read.

**JS**

```js
const fetchJournals = async () => {
    const journals = [];
    
    try {
        // Fetch Journals
        const response = await fetch( "https://core.ac.uk:443/api-v2/journals/search/computer%20science?pageSize=10&apiKey=tM9I3NuzHnOCFyAa1UxW7vBqZK68krT5" ) || {};

        // Throw Error if no response
        if ( response.ok !== true ) throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
        
        // Destruct the json response and get only data array
        const { data=[] } = await response.json() || {};
        
        // Loop over the response data
        for ( const journal of data || [] ){
            // Skip if no journal
            if ( !journal ) continue;

            // Find the url
            const url = journal?.identifiers?.find( s => s.indexOf('url:') === 0 ) || '';

            // Format the data for use
            journals.push({ 
                title: journal.title, 
                url: url.slice(4)
            });
        }
        
        // Add the journals to collection
        setJournals( journals );
    } catch ( error ) {
        // Handle Errors
        console.log( error );
        return null;
    }
    
    // Return journals
    return journals;
}
```

Comment: you're welcome. Also please don't forget to revoke your API Key and generate a new one like @daniel-a-white suggested.